# Spring boot How to prevent multi requests coming from the front-end side?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there a way to prevent **multi requests** from the postman or any other client to the spring boot application?

I mean, I can run a for-loop in `Ajax` as an example and send lots of requests to my controller. how can I prevent that?

Comment: You can't control the behavior of the client application from the backend. Why would you want to prevent that? Why is running AJAX requests in a for-loop an invalid thing for you? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve that is like below,

Create a request filter or interceptor in the spring boot project, and then save the request IP address in a cache server like radis for a predefined time. and then when a request comes, extract the IP address from the request and compare it with the values in the cache, if the value exists, you can return the request before reaching it to the controller, if there is no entry for that IP address in radis, you can save that IP address in radis and parse that request to the controller

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

Comment: So any two clients behind a router would prevent each other from sending requests? That sounds like a recipe for disaster …

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use the following strategy to minimise the impact of the front end sending too many request to the backend :

- In UI layer , implement some UX which would limit the web application to send many request to the backend (e.g disable the submit button for certain seconds after user just submit the form). It can only handle the normal human users but not the api user / robot . But usually more than 95% are the normal users.
- To handle the robot , consider to use some [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) solution for submitting a form. It is mainly used to identify if the request is sent by from the actual robot or human.
- In the back-end web layer , implement some kind of the rate limiting function to decline a request for a particular user or an IP address or api key if that user/IP address/API key call an API for many times within certain period that exceed certain threshold. One of the simple open source rate limiter is [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter) . See [this](https://reflectoring.io/rate-limiting-with-springboot-resilience4j/) for an example of using it in a spring-boot application. The article applies the rate limiter in the service layer but I would apply it in the controller layer.

Answer (score -1):

Very good Question, you need to use circuit breaker to handle that. It will allow you to limit connections if server is down, and after several attempts it will not allow any request. This happens with a use of a fallback method, which will reply immediately to the client, hence, clearing the thread and make your application faster.

[checkout my implementation of this in GitHub](https://github.com/elbashirsaror/stackoverflow/tree/main/SpringBoot/CircuitBreaker)

feel free to add feedback or comment in GitHub

Comment: circuit breaker is used in the client side to handle the case when a client need to call the external service but the external service has slow response or out of service. Apparently the author is not asking any solution for the client side (i.e front-end in this question context)

Comment: You seem to be an expert, but the intention behind the question is clear, if you have an application that sends multiple requests then you need to handle the threads or your application becomes slow. Circuit breaker is the best solution and its configurable...as author asked for spring boot solution.... if don't the answer asking for front-end solution, because he would've simply disabled the button or whatever function send the multiple requests.

Comment: you touch the point. circuit breaker is used when the spring-boot application need to send multiple request to the external server. the author does not mentioned his spring-boot application need to do that. The spring-boot application is only receiving the request but not sending